# How to pass another value from a "class" to a "function"

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, I have called a WebService (REST) by using a `.map` to a function (that is outside the class). I automatically get an object "response" that's fine. But now, how can I send a value that is inside my method (and my class) to the function that is outside of the class? This value has nothing to do with WebService response.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {

  getEvents(myValue: string): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {

    this.http
      .get("url of webservice")
      .map(mapEvents) <- how can I put "myValue" here
      .catch(handleError);
 }
}

function mapEvents(response: Response): CalendarEvent[] {
  return response.json().map(toEvent);
}

function toEvent(event: any): CalendarEvent {
  const s_event = <CalendarEvent>(
    {
      value : myValue;   <- to get "myValue" here? 
    });
  return s_event;
}
```

Comment: You can't, it's not available there. You'd have to pass it in explicitly, e.g. `.map(event => mapEvents(event, myValue))`.

Comment: The question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {

  getEvents(myValue: string): Observable<CalendarEvent[]> {

    this.http
      .get("url of webservice")
      .map(d => mapEvents(d, myValue)) <-  put "myValue" here
      .catch(handleError);
 }
}

function mapEvents(response: Response, myValue): CalendarEvent[] {
  return response.json().map(e => toEvent(e, myValue));
}

function toEvent(event: any, myValue): CalendarEvent {
  const s_event = <CalendarEvent>(
    {
      value : myValue;   <- to get "myValue" her !
    });
  return s_event;
}
```